# How to use React HashRouter for route parameters?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two routes, a base path and a customer route. The customer route takes a customerId parameter.

```html
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/mapper/:mappingId/" exact component={Mapper}/>
      <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
```

then in the react component I am calling it like this to navigate

```html
      window.open(`/customer/${customerId}`)
```

(updated, still doesn't work)

but when I navigate it just goes to the App component. I have to use HashRouter because the react app is wrapped in Electron. BrowserRouter works on the web

The url i get when i navigate is this:
http://localhost:3000/customer/ca023754-bb75-4f64-a19c-958525b53e12#/
I also tried adding backslash in Route,  /customer/:customerId/, that didn't work as well

I have read [How to use React Router with Electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505404/how-to-use-react-router-with-electron) but it doesn't really work

Comment: It might be a good idea to place the '/' first with exact path and also put your routes inside a switch.

Comment: I updated the code snippet and tried to put "exact" before and after path variables. Doesn't work still

Comment: Put the default route '/' first.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. Hashrouter expect the url to have "#/" after the basepath. so it should be window.open('#/customer/${customerId}')